# Filling in white spaces on div hide/show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the code to hide certain div's on click which I have shown in the pictures below, but how would I have the tiles fill in the white spaces on the hidden div's and then get back to their spot upon showing the boxes again?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68XMV.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijk7G.png)

Code:

```css
.decisionTreeBox {
 background-color: #4B92DB;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeOneDrive {
 background-color: #094AB2;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeProject {
 background-color: #3C8B12;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeSharePoint {
 background-color: #008CE7;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeTeams {
 background-color: #4A1EBD;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreePlanner {
 background-color: #247D0E;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeYammer {
 background-color: #39A4C1;
 color: white;
 width: 300px;
 height: 140px;
 display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

#innerBoxHeadings {
 color: white!important; 
 text-align: center; 
 padding-top: 5px;
}

#columnMiddleBorderLeft, #pageTitle {
 display:none!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="projects" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
      Collaborate on Projects</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="files" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
      Collaborate on Files</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-collaborate="socially" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
      Collaborate Socially</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                    <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <script>
            function projectCollab(){
                var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
                    attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

                for(var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++){
                    var d = divsToCange[i];

                    if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr){
                        d.style.display = (!d.style.display) ? 'none' : '';
                    }else{
                        d.style.display = '';
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

            for(var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++){
                divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
            }
            </script>
</div>
```

### Update

I have chosen Fadi's path and I have placed them all in one row.

Here is the current issue that I am having with Fadi's code:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkGX.png

I want there to be margin-top space between the second row of columns at all times, how can one achieve this without a second row?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried changing `else{d.style.display = '';}` into `else{d.style.display = 'flex';}` ? I haven't worked with flexbox before, but something tells me that if you have display:flex in the css and then overwrite it with nothing, your layouting relying on flexbox will break.

Comment: @shilly, let me try to see if this can be updated and if it works.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents: You should mark Fadi's answer as accepted.

Comment: @fnostro Just did that! Thanks for the input, I'm still getting the hang of stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you should do 
first of all put all the bootstrap columns inside one row only

second point is this piece of js

```
            for(var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++){
                var d = divsToCange[i];
                if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr){
                    d.parentNode.style.display ='none' ;
                }
                else{
                    d.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
```

here is the full html + JS

```
<div class="outer-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="projects" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
                    Collaborate on Projects</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="files" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
                    Collaborate on Files</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-collaborate="socially" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
                    Collaborate Socially</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeOneDrive"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>OneDrive</h3></div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Project</h3></div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>SharePoint</h3></div>
                </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeTeams"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Teams</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreePlanner"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Planner</h3></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">
                <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer"><h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;"/>Yammer</h3></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        function projectCollab(){
            var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
                attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

            for(var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++){
                var d = divsToCange[i];
                console.log("2@ ",attr)
                if(d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr){
                    d.parentNode.style.display ='none' ;
                }
                else{
                    d.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

        for(var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++){
            divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
        }
        </script>
```

**EDIT**
for the spacing issue please define this in your style tag

```
    <style>

.margin-bottom-20{
    margin-bottom:20px;
  }
... rest of your styles
```

i have also updated the html to take the class name as shown above 
all i did is `<div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom-20" style="text-align: center;">`

Comment: This works perfectly @Fadi, how can I make the second set of div's always have a margin from the top? Have top margin in second row where "Teams" "Planner" and "Yammer" are?

Comment: you can easily give a class called "margin-bottom"  for all  divs containing .col-md-4  like this
  .margin-bottom{
    margin-bottom:20px;
  }

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents also please if you find the solution working please mark it as accepted answer thanks

Comment: I've tried adding a new <div> before Teams div and defining a style of margin, but for whatever reason, anytime the tiles go to the top, it leaves a margin on the top then.

Comment: just do the following 
<div class="col-md-4 margin-bottom " style="text-align: center;">

and in your styles just add this class  .margin-bottom{ margin-bottom:20px; }

Comment: Thanks for the input again, I've tried adding the margin-bottom to the class and defining it, but it's having the same problem where those bottom apps go to the top, then it leaves a margin on the top also https://i.imgur.com/eReg8KG.png

Comment: please test the edit i did @SaintLouisEvents and tell if it works

Comment: You are the man! Works flawlessly, I have upvoted and chosen this answer as best answer. Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172782/discussion-between-saintlouis-events-and-fadi-abo-msalam).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function projectCollab() {
      var divsToCange = document.querySelectorAll('[data-decision]'),
        attr = this.getAttribute('data-collaborate');

      for (var i = 0; i < divsToCange.length; i++) {
        var d = divsToCange[i];

        if (d.getAttribute('data-decision') == attr) {
          d.style.display = (!d.style.display) ? 'none' : '';
        } else {
          d.style.display = '';
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    var divButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-collaborate]');

    for (var i = 0; i < divButtons.length; i++) {
      divButtons[i].addEventListener('click', projectCollab);
    }
```

```css
.decisionTreeBox {
  background-color: #4B92DB;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeOneDrive {
  background-color: #094AB2;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeProject {
  background-color: #3C8B12;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeSharePoint {
  background-color: #008CE7;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeTeams {
  background-color: #4A1EBD;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreePlanner {
  background-color: #247D0E;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#decisionTreeYammer {
  background-color: #39A4C1;
  color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 140px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#innerBoxHeadings {
  color: white!important;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

#columnMiddleBorderLeft,
#pageTitle {
  display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="projects" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
        Collaborate on Projects</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="files" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
        Collaborate on Files</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
      <div data-collaborate="socially" class="decisionTreeBox" style="font-size: larger;">
        Collaborate Socially</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeOneDrive">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/onedrive-logo.png" style="width: 65px; height: 65px; padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />OneDrive</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="projects" id="decisionTreeProject">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/Project.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Project</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeSharePoint">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/SharePointDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />SharePoint</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="files" id="decisionTreeTeams">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/TeamsDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Teams</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreePlanner">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/PlannerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Planner</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
        <div data-decision="socially" id="decisionTreeYammer">
          <h3 id="innerBoxHeadings"><img src="/TrainingResourceCenter/O365Training/PublishingImages/YammerDecisionTree.png" style="padding-bottom: 5px; padding-right: 10px; vertical-align: middle;" />Yammer</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin-top: 40px;">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Does this work?

Comment: Hey @Sheshank, thanks for the input but unfortunately, it hasn't done much on my end and now the boxes don't show again on click, so I have reverted the code. I do appreciate the help!

Comment: There's still a bunch of whitespace in the code snippet. I dont understand the reasoning either why changing the transparency of an element would collapse its position.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Are you sure you are putting it in properly?? It works fine in the code snippet runner

Comment: @Shilly The transparency keeps it in the same place without any display.

Comment: @SaintLouisEvents Your question is how to remove the tiles and then making that area white right?

Comment: @Shilly Wait is the question how to collapse its position??? I thought it was what ohhhhhh never mind this is wrong

Comment: @SheshankShankar That's how I interpreted it yes, the pics shown have like the arrows where the OP expects the elements to slide to. But I don't know how it interacts with flexbox and such.

Comment: Ohhh Okay i see

Comment: @SheshankShankar I have checked out your code, and it was super close but I have tested out Fadi's below and it seems to be doing the required job of filling in all the spaces. I do appreciate your help so much tho! Will upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a combination of `jQuery` and [CSS grid-auto-flow Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid-auto-flow.asp)
to achieve the effect.

I also used `toggle()` method to toggle visibility as a test.

---

```js
$('.item1').click((e) => {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".item5, .item6").toggle();
});
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}

[class^='item'] {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="grid-container controller" style="grid-auto-flow: row;">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item4">4</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="grid-container" style="grid-auto-flow: row;">
  <div class="item5">1</div>
  <div class="item6">2</div>
  <div class="item7">3</div>
  <div class="item8">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Alex! Unfortunately, this doesn't work with my pre-defined CSS in our SharePoint tenant.